# WP ошибка 'Illegal string offset ' для SVG изображений задаваемых через виджеты

Tags: php, wordpress, вёрстка, svg, виджет

Столкнулся с проблемой вывода предупреждения перед отображением в теге img

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/html/wp-includes/media.php on line 1179Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/html/wp-includes/media.php on line 1180
```

при выводе изображения формата SVG в стандартных виджетах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На форумах пишут, что это связано с тем, что WP не дружит с загруженными svg, WP не может найти для SVG правильные размеры.
Как можно решить эту проблему? (используется php 7.4 WP 5.6)

Comment: У вас не WP5.6. В 5.6 в этих строках комментарии.

Comment: Да, вы правы / былы 5.5 /// Обновил до 5.6 проблема все равно не ушла просто теперь в другой строке / (Первое сообщение поправил)

Answer (score 2):

В своё время у меня были подобные проблемы.
Я уже и не помню точно, как их решил, что-то менял в стилях классов, которые отвечают за вывод изображений.
Мне тогда не очень нравилось всё это.
Решил эту проблему и делаю до сих пор добавление изображений svg на сайт WP с помощью тега `<object>`
Изображение можно вставить в HTML в любом месте странички, любого размера, к тому же оно будет интерактивным.

В примере ниже размер `200x200px`

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/animation/dasharray/Circle-progress.svg" width="200" height="200">
</object>
```

`width="400"` `height="400"`

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://svg-art.ru/files/animation/dasharray/dasharrayMask2.svg" width="400" height="400">
</object>
```

[Пример, как это выглядит на сайте WP](https://svg-art.ru/?p=1783)

Comment: Просто svg на сайт выводиться если это не через кастомайзер / Там Warning не возникает. Только тут, если с размерами проблема

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Не подошло решение? Я тоже с этими виджетами маялся, но нашел решение, как в ответе выше и сейчас никаких проблем. Просто одну строчку c `object` добавляешь и всё работает. К тому же заметил при добавлении через виджет образовывалась дополнительная страница в WP с одной только картинкой. Что есть плохо для SEO

Comment: Мне просто не очень данное решение тут подходит, в данном случаи заполнением сайта будет заниматься совершенно другой человек и харткодить svg через object мне нельзя. Мне бы глобальное решение на уровне php а не временное

Comment: @BlackStar1991 понятно, то есть через скрипты будете добавлять, я то понял сначала, что вручную, через виджеты, что само по себе более трудоемко. Я не настаиваю, но ведь и в php можно написать код, где из папки с SVG можно брать файлы и оборачивать их тем же скриптом в `object` и добавлять в HTML